# An interesting postcard

Tags: translation, handwriting

According to my information, this postcard was sent from Japan to Russia, and probably in 1945.
Needs a translation badly and nobody has seemed to care since then. I suppose that the historical kana usage can take place here.
[image: Front of the postcard]
[image: Back of the postcard]

P.S.: Yes, a translation request, but definitely not the usual case, somewhat intricate, otherwise I would be able to translate it myself. Yet feel free to close it if you think that it just does not fit.

Comment: OMG First time I have ever been moved by something on SE!  This postcard belongs in a museum with two addresses on it --- both were parts of Japan back then but both are foreign countries now. Incredible!

Comment: They will close this thread shortly, I am sure.  If they do, contact me by leaving a message in the chat room.  I can read and understand every single character and word on this with no problems.

Comment: @TokyoNagoya The community decides what to close, so if people don't vote to close a question (even if it would normally be considered off-topic), it will stay open forever :-)

Comment: http://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/8483045.html I made a question about this on 教えて！goo. Answer No.2 notes a lot of the same things which I found strange about this text but no definite answer...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

郵便はがき postcard. 大日本 Dai Nippon "big Japan" or "Japanese empire". 樺太 Kara Futo, Sakhalin. 大泊町 Oh Tomari Cho, literally means "big harbor town". 東 east. 三条 3rd street. 南 south. 一ノ十一 one hyphen eleven.

髙橋 Taka Hashi, family name. 久男 Hisa O, a male name. 様 polite addressing like "Sir".

北満 Hoku Man, northern Manchuria. 龍江省 a Chinese geometric name, literally means "dragon river state". 狐池(fox pond) or 狐地(fox land). ニテ means "at", he wrote this letter at the 狐池 in 龍江省 of 北満. 久友 Hisa Tomo, a male name, the writer of this letter. 満巽 Man Tatsumi, I don't know what Man Tatsumi means.

謹賀新年 A Happy New Year. 皆 everyone. すこやかに healthy. 元気 vigorous. です is (indicates present tense).

手紙 a letter. 一通 one, 通 tsu is a numerical unit (nominal measure word) for letters. を indicates object of a verb. 出しません don't write.

でした was (indicates past tense, I didn't drop a line). が but/although. 然して (shikou si te) although. 悪い bad. 心 heart.

から from. でわありません is not.

此の this. 写眞 or 写真 photo. は is/equals. 北満 northern Manchuria. - The following two characters I can't read; it is の町 "town of" - thanks  Earthliŋ :-)

の of. 夕 evening. X(寒 cold) -> O(暮 sunset) - thanks Tokyo Nagoya :-)

支 China. 満 Manchuria. の of. 雪 snow.

Comment: Amazing to me that anyone could decipher that

Comment: I think [満]{みつる} and [巽]{たつみ？} are male names.

Comment: It seems to me that the recipient location is the 大泊町{おおどまりちょう} town and 東三条南 can be a whole street name toponym written in kana as ひがしさんじょうみなみ.

Answer (score 5):

Front upper:

> 郵便はがき *Post Card* (right-to-left)
>
> 大日本樺太大泊町
>   東三条南一ノ十一
>   *1-11 Higashisanjō-Minami* (South of East 3rd St.)*, Ōdomari-chō* (town, now Korsakov)*, Karafuto* (Sakhalin)*, (EMPIRE OF) JAPAN* (recipient's address)
>
> 髙久男様 *Mr. Hisao Takahashi* (recipient)
>   <sup>(Not sure if 髙 is the legal name or merely handwriting variant of standard 高橋)</sup>
>
> 北満龍江省ノ孤地ニテ
>   *At (=from) a remotest place in Ryūkō* (Longjiang) *Province, Northern Manchuria*
>
> 久友 *Hisatomo(?)*
>   巽 *Tatsumi*
>   満 *Mitsuru(?)* (senders)
>   <sup>(lack of family names suggests they are of the same family with the recipient)</sup>

Front lower:

> 謹賀新年 *Happy New Year*
>
> <s>□す</s> <sub>(□ seems to be an erroneously written 比 instead of 皆)</sub>
>
> 皆すこやかに元気です
>   手紙一通を出しません <sub>(を may be an error of も)</sub>
>   でしたが然して悪い心
>   からでわありません <sub>(わ should be は in correct spelling)</sub>
>   *Everybody is fine and healthy.*
>   *We did not send a single letter* (or *one of letters*)*, but that was not out of ill will.*
>
> 此の寫眞は北満の町
>   の夕暮
>   *The photograph is dusk of a town in northern Manchuria.*
>
> <sup>(The text contains an apparent error and sounds somewhat stiff.)</sup>

Back:

> 雪の滿支 *Chinese continent in snow* (right-to-left)
>   <sup>(This is the name of a picture postcard series)</sup>

[image]